# Bad display of dates before 1000AD in Google Chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

If I pass Google Charts API (timeline chart) this date:

```
Date(1, 0, 1)
```

I get year 2001.

Do you know how to get year **1AD**?

`Date(0001,0,1)` doesn't work neither.

Comment: More info in google bug tracker: https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=1468

Comment: And the bug is verified.

Answer (score 1):

If you enter your dates like this:

```
new Date(1, 0, 1)
```

they start in 1900, but you can correct them by looping over the DataTable and setting the full year on each date:

```
// assumes date is column 0 in your DataTable 'data'
for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
     var date = data.getValue(i, 0);
     date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() - 1900);
     data.setValue(i, 0, date);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have change a litte your code. However got error from timeline JS: Error: Problem parsing d="MNaN,0LNaN,40.992" dygraph,format+pl,default+pl,ui+pl,timeline+pl.I.js:467

Comment: Data passed to date.setFullYear() seems  to be correct, according to console: 1, 2, 3, 4 etc.

Comment: @Pablo Sorry, however the answer had typo error (data,date) and can't be implemented to Google Timeline API (2 columns required: begin, end). So Code here: for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
                    for (var j = 2; j < data.getNumberOfColumns(); j++) {
                        var date = data.getValue(i, j);
                        console.log(date.getFullYear()-1900);
                        date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() - 1900);
                        data.setValue(i, j, date);
                    }
                }

Comment: @Pable Nope, any of answer didn't solved a problem. Asgallant's method outputs Error: Problem parsing d="MNaN,0LNaN,40.992" dygraph,format+pl,default+pl,ui+pl,timeline+pl.I.js:467

Comment: I fixed the typo in my answer.  If you are having problems implementing this, please update your question with a code example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I have implemented it, however there is probably a bug in API, becouse it throw an error: http://jsbin.com/jaxo/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date("0001-01-01T00:00");
```

will return

```
Mon Jan 01 1 01:00:00 GMT+0100
```

GMT could be different for your result.

**Update:** See [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/EYEyEBU/1/edit). For that type of date format like:

```
  dataTable.addRows([
    [ 'Washington', new Date("0090-03-29T00:00"), new Date("0097-02-03T00:00") ],
    [ 'Adams',      new Date("0097-02-03T00:00"), new Date("0101-02-03T00:00") ],
    [ 'Jefferson',  new Date("0101-02-03T00:00"), new Date("0109-02-03T00:00") ]]);
```

or

```
  dataTable.addRows([
    [ 'Washington', new Date("0040-03-29T00:00"), new Date("0097-02-03T00:00") ],
    [ 'Adams',      new Date("0097-02-03T00:00"), new Date("0101-02-03T00:00") ],
    [ 'Jefferson',  new Date("0101-02-03T00:00"), new Date("0109-02-03T00:00") ]]);
```

it works until I try to set year less than 40. After that it breaks down with error:

```
Error: Problem parsing d="MNaN,0LNaN,40.992"
...
Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute x="NaN"
```

**Update:** Following [this articel](http://www.scholarslab.org/research-and-development/parsing-bc-dates-with-javascript/) I founds out that the following could be also used (notice the two leading zeros and + sign, minus sign should be used for years BC):

```
new Date('+000001')
```

produce:

```
Mon Jan 01 1 01:00:00 GMT+0100
```

Comment: Error: Uncaught TypeError: Object Date("0072-01-01T00:00") has no method 'getTimezoneOffset'

Comment: I'll check with my example of timeline chart how it works. That is valid date but I never tried something like that with timeline

Comment: :( http://jsbin.com/atulIxa/1/edit Now, tried to modify yours. 2 things, I need years 1-300AD (game), and have json data.

Comment: Look http://jsbin.com/kudaf/1/edit this "+000001" doesn't work with timeline neither

Answer (score -1):

This is 8 year old article. I was looking for the same functionality - able to display old dates using google charts "timelines" . It seems to work until 360 AD, any thing below it is breaking.

> google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
> google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
> function drawChart() {
> var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
> var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
> var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
>
> ```
>     dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
>     dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
>     dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
>     dataTable.addRows([
>       [ 'Washington', new Date( (**359**-1970)*365*86400000), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
>       [ 'Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
>       [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]]);
>
>     chart.draw(dataTable);
>   }
> ```

https://jsfiddle.net/pxr87/9rwh6vfb/8/

I calculated milliseconds since the data 1970 for date.
new Date( (**359**-1970)*365*86400000). It works for 359AD but not to 358 AD.
86.4 milliseconds per day.

What I find it bizarre is some times it works only 550 AD, and other times it only works until 400 AD.

I appreciate any help.
thank you

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33730355)